# Error while using waitkey() in openCV

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have been working on a very simple python code for taking video input.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Capturing video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
ret, frame = cap.read() #Ret returns whether it's true or false
cv2.imshow('Image',frame)

if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but, while executing, it's showing an error like this...

```
line 11, in <module>
if cv2.waitkey(0) & 0xff == ord('q'):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'waitkey'
```

What is the way out? I am using Python 2.7.13 and openCV 2.4.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `cv2.waitKey()` not `cv2.waitkey()`.

Answer (score 1):

The K is capital in cv2.waitKey() , write

```
if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff) == ord('q'):
    break
```

Comment: @D.Mitra You can mark this answer as a verified solution

Answer (score -1):

Simply replace cv2.waitkey(1) with cv2.wait**K**ey(1)